# Clojure: understaning the binding in a doseq

Tags: clojure

I understand the following snippet of code and its corresponding output

```
(let  [ [x y] (map list [1 2] [3 4])]  (prn x) (prn y))
(1 3)
(2 4)
nil
```

Now the following output confuses me:

```
(doseq [ [x y] (map list [1 2] [3 4])] (prn x y))
1 3
2 4
nil
```

I think in the above snippet x will get bound to [1 3] and y will get bound to [2 4] so the output should be"

```
1 2
3 4
nil
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding is pulling out the individual elements inside the larger single element in the nesting. The map creates a list `((1 3) (2 4)` so the element `1 3` is first and thus that is what the doseq outputs: this is "destructuring" and the `x` and `y` are *both* bound from inside a *single* element of the list. Thus x and y are 1 and 3, and then 2 and 4.

Note also that this is the same binding that occurs in a `for` and the destructuring works for all sequence types.

Answer (score 3):

Let's isolate the source of your confusion.

```
(map list [1 2] [3 4])
```

evaluates to

```
((1 3) (2 4))
```

So your first example

```
(let [[x y] (map list [1 2] [3 4])]  (prn x) (prn y))
```

... is equivalent to

```
(let [[x y] [[1 3] [2 4]]] (prn x) (prn y))
```

... or, printing slightly differently

```
(let [[x y] [[1 3] [2 4]]] (prn [x y]))
```

... which simplifies to

```
(let [z [[1 3] [2 4]]] (prn z))
```

... producing, as expected,

```
; [[1 3] [2 4]]
; nil
```

So far, so good.

If we boil down the confusing example,

```
(doseq [ [x y] (map list [1 2] [3 4])] (prn x y))
```

... in the same way, we get, taking the liberty of printing each `z` whole,

```
(doseq [z [[1 3] [2 4]]] (prn z))
```

which fairly clearly produces the observed order:

```
[1 3]
[2 4]
nil
```

The difference is that the `doseq` binds `z` to each successive vector in `[[1 3] [2 4]]`, so we don't see an enclosing `[ ... ]`, whereas the `let` binds `z` once to the whole thing.